# Using another table as value type

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been searching this and can not find the proper answer if I need an JOIN or SUBQUERY, I have tried multiple ways if doing this and honestly I am hitting a major wall.  I am trying to do something simple and I don't know how to progress

I have two tables I am trying to use: table 1) data 2) mapping

table 1 is like this the headers are :

```
Date
Value1 
Value2 
Value3
Value4 
Etc.
```

Value in CSV style for example would be:

```
1/1/10,1,2,3,4
1/2/10,5,6,7,8
1/3/10,9,10,11,12
```

table 2 has only one row though, here are the headers and one row

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4
```

The one row would be like:

```
Description1, Description2, Description3, Description4
```

So, I want to be able to, for example do a SELECT FROM table 1 and join in the Description for each matching row where the Column names are the same, so sample output based on the above would be to be like this:

```
1/1/10,1,Description1,2,Description2,3,Description3,4,Description4
1/2/10,5,Description1,6,Description2,7,Description3,8,Description4
```

Etc

Comment: If I understand, you want everything from table1, and mix in one row from table2? That's doable, but it's really odd. There's probably a better way to do it. What's this doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's just one row in `table2` and no key, you can simply join it.

```
select *
from table1
join table2
```

Since there's just one row in `table2` it's questionable why it exists at all. This could be done without a join at all.

```
select date, value1, 'Description1', value2, 'Description2', value3, 'Description3', value4, 'Description4'
from table1;
```

---

There's likely a better way to do this. Having columns like `value1`, `value2`, and `value3` usually indicates poor table design. Instead of having four value columns, you should have four value *rows*. And instead of having a table with four columns of descriptions, it should be four *rows* of descriptions.

For example, let's say you're storing items in an order. An order can have many items. Rather than having a column for each item in an order like `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, you'd have a row for each item in a join table. Below that's `order_items`. Descriptions of the items is stored separately in its own table, one row per item.

```
user
----
id bigint primary key
name text not null

items
-----
id bigint primary key
name text not null

orders
------
id bigint primary key
user_id bigint references users(id)
created_at datetime

order_items
-----------
order_id bigint references orders(id)
item_id bigint references items(id)
```

If you want to look up all the items in an order, with their names, you'd use the `order_items` table to get all the items in an order, and join with the `items` table to get each item's name.

```
select i.name
from order_items oi
join items i on i.id = oi.item_id
where oi.order_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma separated lists of values are awkward to handle.

Rather than a CSV, storing the values in a mapping table is typically used.

If I understand correctly then I believe that the following may demonstrate along the lines of what you want:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1 /* Assigned Values per date (the mapping table)*/;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS table2 /* Values */;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (valueid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,value_description TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (date TEXT, valueid_reference INTEGER REFERENCES table2(valueid),value INTEGER, UNIQUE(date, valueid_reference));
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1,'Value1 Description'),(2,'Value2 Description'),(3,'Value3 Description'),(4,'Value4 Description');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    ('1/1/10',1,1),('1/1/10',2,2),('1/1/10',3,3),('1/1/10',4,4),
    ('1/2/10',1,5),('1/2/10',2,6),('1/2/10',3,7),('1/2/10',4,8)
;
SELECT date||','||group_concat(value||','||value_description) AS all_values_and_descriptions FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON valueid_reference = valueid GROUP BY date;
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

This results in :-

[image]

- Noting that the REFRENCES (Foreign Key) will be a noop unless Foreign Key support is enabled. However, without it will still work.

As can be seen each value per date is an individual row in table 1 (so 4 rows per date). It is the **group_concat** function that is used to get all the values per date in conjunction with the GROUP BY clause which creates a set of rows (a Group) for each date.

The 2nd SELECT shows the rows in table1 :-

[image]